# Quartz Scheduler using database

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz to schedule cron jobs in my web application. i am using a oracle Databse to store jobs and related info. When i add the jobs in the Database, i need to re-start the server/application (tomcat server) for these new jobs to get scheduled. How can i add jobs in the database and  make them work without restarting the server.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean you are using `JDBCJobStore`? In that case it is not ideal to make direct changes in the database tables storing the job data. However, I suppose you could set up a separate job that runs every X minutes / hours, checks whether there are new jobs in the database (that need to be scheduled), and schedule them as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Add jobs via the Scheduler API.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/best_practices.html